# Setting custom service class names for different WSDL versions with wsdl2java

Tags: soap, cxf, soap-client, wsdl2java

I'm developing a SOAP client based on Apache CXF. The Java classes for accessing the webservices are generated using the Maven plugin of `wsdl2java`. There are two WSDLs which define a service (`InfoService`) in two different versions:

- info_service_v1.wsdl
- info_service_v2.wsdl

Internally, both WSDLs use the identical naming, i.e. the generated webservice class is in each case named `InfoService`.

Is it possible to specify another name depending on the used WSDL?

**Example**:

- `info_service_v1.wsdl` --> InfoServiceV1
- `info_service_v2.wsdl` --> InfoServiceV2

Answer (score 0):

In wsdl2java, you can set the option `-sn service-name` in order to change the service name for both versions.
Another option is to generate each version of code in a different package with option `-p package-name`

Comment: The option `-sn` only selects a specific service if there are multiple services in the WSDL. It does not support renaming the service interface. Guess I'll have to use specific packages.